# batch mysql script / schedule run the batch job

Tags: mysql, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to create a batch or a text file to execute .sql ?

Let say :

script location : C:\test.sql
Hostname : host.name
Port : 1000
user : me
password : pw

---

test.sql -- >

```
select * from table1 ;quit;
```

---

How can I put all these into a .bat so that I can use the window to schedule the job to run in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in a .bat called `C:\RunSQL.bat`

Make sure `C:\RunSQL.bat` looks like this:

```
@echo off
mysql -hhostname -P1000 -ume -ppw -AN < C:\test.sql
```

then just run it

```
RunSQL.bat
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: when you say run it, how do you actually run them ? Start>Run.. > then type in "C:\> RunSQL.bat    ??

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, my background is not computer. :-)